# How can I handle the wait_for_selector function's TimeoutError in Playwright-python?

Tags: python, exception, playwright-python

I want to use `Except TimeoutError` to handle the timeout problem. But the script always throws me a TimeoutError, not print a message as I planed.

Here is my code:

```py
try:
    await page.wait_for_selector("#winiframe_main", timeout=10000, state='detached')
    print("The frame is detached.")
except TimeoutError:
    print("The frame is not detached")
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5):

You have to import `TimeoutError` from `playwright` to catch this exception:

```
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, TimeoutError
```

Comment: ... and use this if you're using the sync API: `from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright, TimeoutError`

Answer (score 0):

It kept on throwing an error with the imported TimeoutError, so I left it out all together. Plus had to disable a flake8 error with `# noqa`

````py
try:
  // some selector that might fail
  page.locator("whatever")
except: # noqa: E722
  print("Not today")
```
````